RecyclerView ListAdapter with Multiple ViewTypes not displaying both views properly
I'm having trouble coding the Adapter for a nested recyclerView setup. Decided to have one adapter with multiple viewTypes rather than two separate adapters for the child and and parent recyclerView. Here's what I've managed to do so far:
class RecommendationRecipeAdapter: ListAdapter<RecommendationRecipe, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(DiffUtilCallback()) {
    private val converter = Converters()

    // Companion object to hold the view types
    companion object {
        private const val viewTypeParent = 0
        private const val viewTypeChildren = 1
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if (position % 2 == 0) {
            viewTypeParent
        } else {
            viewTypeChildren
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)

        return when (viewType) {
            viewTypeParent -> ParentViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_date, parent, false))
            viewTypeChildren -> ChildViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_food,parent,false))
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Please provide a valid viewType")
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val index = position / 2  // Convert position to index in the original dataset
        val item = getItem(index)

        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            if (holder is ParentViewHolder) {
                holder.bind(item)
            }
        } else {
            if (holder is ChildViewHolder) {
                holder.bind(item)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return super.getItemCount() * 2
    }

    inner class ParentViewHolder(itemView: View) : BaseViewHolder(itemView) {
        val dateTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDate)

        override fun bind(item: RecommendationRecipe) {
            val date = converter.formatDayDateToString(item.recommendation?.date)
            dateTextView.text = date
        }
    }

    inner class ChildViewHolder(itemView: View) : BaseViewHolder(itemView) {
        val tvName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name)
        val tvIngredients: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_ingredients)
        val tvCalories: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_calories)
        val tvProtein: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_protein)
        val tvFat: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_fat)
        val tvCarbs: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_carbs)

        override fun bind(item: RecommendationRecipe) {
            tvName.text = item.recipe?.name
            tvIngredients.text = item.recipe?.ingredients
            tvCalories.text = item.recipe?.calories.toString()
            tvProtein.text = item.recipe?.protein.toString()
            tvFat.text = item.recipe?.fat.toString()
            tvCarbs.text = item.recipe?.carbs.toString()
        }
    }

}

abstract class BaseViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    abstract fun bind(item: RecommendationRecipe)
}

internal class DiffUtilCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<RecommendationRecipe>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(
        oldItem: RecommendationRecipe,
        newItem: RecommendationRecipe
    ): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(
        oldItem: RecommendationRecipe,
        newItem: RecommendationRecipe
    ): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}

The RecommendationRecipe is a data class for wrapping Recommendation and Recipe together since ListAdapter only accepts one data model:
data class RecommendationRecipe(
    @Embedded val recommendation: Recommendation?,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "recipe_id",
        entityColumn = "recipeId"
    )
    val recipe: Recipe?
)

The code above initially works fine and as expected, and this is how it looks like:
enter image description here
Between Breakfast, Lunch and Dinner, the displayed recipe are 2, 3 and 2 respectively. Changing between viewing Breakfast and Dinner is completely fine. But when I click Lunch to display its recipes and go back to viewing either Breakfast or Dinner it crashes and raises the following error:
                                                                                                   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionChildViewHolder{39148ce position=4 id=-1, oldPos=5, pLpos:5 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached no parent} androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{905cbf7 VFED..... ......I. 33,786-1047,2780 #7f09033a app:id/weeklyRecommendationRecyclerView}, , layout:androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager@43d54cd
I've tried multiple solutions like modifying the logic for getItemViewType
and changing how I map the data but none worked so far except for adding the
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return super.getItemCount() * 2
    }

But changing between Breakfast, Lunch and Dinner crashes the app and I haven't found the solution to this as well. Tried removing the getItemCount() to see if the recyclerView displays correctly without it, but nope:
enter image description here
Strangely, however, this time the app doesn't crash and raise the error above no matter how many times I changed between Breakfast, Lunch and Dinner. So, neither possible options are viable right now.
I tried removing
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return super.getItemCount() * 2
    }

Which is the only solution that worked, but it the app crashes after changing between breakfast, lunch and inner several times.
Tried removing it, but the recyclerView doesn't inflate as expected.

val item = getItem(position / 2) this doesn't make sense to me.
ListAdapter only accepts one data model.  Actually this is incorrect. You can pass multiple data models using sealed class.

I used sealed classes to pass both the Recommendation and Recipe models into the adapter and it worked perfectly. Much appreciated, brother.
